# Swift: How to get the Registration Token of Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement google cloud messaging in one of my project, where a type-A user submit something, it will push the information to the server and it will send to a type-B user. If the type-B user agree the things that the type-A user sent, they would say yes and it will send that to server and return the information to the type-A user.

That's the idea. So, I follow the example at https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm, however I can only get the registration token printed on the output. If I want to get/retrieve the registration token to pass to the server, how could I achieve it?

[image]

In here, I've got the registration token called from AppDelegate and printed out, how can I return/get it outside of the AppDelegate?
Also, how could I notify the user when they turn off the screen? (send notification) Right now, I only receive notification from the input)

Thank you for reading the question. Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the Step 4 of [Obtain a registration token](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift#obtain_a_registration_token) which provides a code on passing the registration token to the server. In notifying user when screen is off, check [Setting the lifespan of a message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl). It says: "If the device is connected but idle, the message will still be delivered right away unless the `delay_while_idle` flag is set to true." as long as the device is connected it will receive notifications.

Comment: I checked the link to "Setting the lifespan of a message" but couldn't find the delay_while_idle flag anywhere in the [AppDelegate](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift) or the [ViewController](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExampleSwift/ViewController.swift) .However, I found that in the function didReceiveRemoteNotification, the notification is received and the NSNotificationCenter is called, What could I do with these to send the notifications to users?